# Deallocating properties in didReceiveMemoryWarning

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am really struggling in understanding what to do in `didReceiveMemoryWarning`. From what I read on StackOverflow and blogs, the following is my understanding -

Generate all data that your view needs in `viewDidAppear` and destroy those (set to `nil`) in `didReceiveMemoryWarning`. This sounds good to me because those properties can be recreated in `viewDidAppear`.

However, the problem is that `didReceiveMemoryWarning` is also called for the view which is currently visible. In this case, obviously I would not deallocate data for the view. Shouldn't `didReceiveMemoryWarning` NOT be called for the view which is currently visible. But that is not case - How can one handle this?

Answer (score 0):

The Idea with `didReceiveMemoryWarning` is that any **Data** that you have that can be re-created, should be `deallocated` and created from that point on whenever the user needs it. Traditionally, this doesn't include UI components.

So unless you have a ton of UIControls on your screen, it's probably not worth it to write the code to re-cycle, or recreate them (especially since this is done for you in `UICollection`'s and `UITableView`'s). That said, if you're getting a `didReceiveMemoryWarning`, it's probably because you're keeping some stuff in memory around that you don't need.

Comment: On every view controller didAppear I am getting data from the server and storing them in properties. Should I not set these properties to `nil` when getting a `didReceiveMemoryWarning`.

Comment: Yes you should, that is if you're not doing anything else with them. Something I forgot to ask, are you using ARC?

Comment: Yes, I am using ARC. Mostly I think that properties which are created in `viewDidAppear` should be set to `nil` in `didReceiveMemoryWarning`. The problem is that `didReceiveMemoryWarning` is called on the currently visible view for which the properties should not be set to `nil`. Also, the properties are `strong` in the views. Thoughts?

Comment: What is your main UIControl in the ViewController? Is it a UITableView or UICollection? Or something else?

Comment: In most cases it's UITableView. The data which is used to populate it comes from the server - gets populated in `viewDidAppear` with a call to the server and then the table is reloaded.

Comment: Are you storing your data retrieved from the user in a `NSArray`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56790/discussion-between-siddharth-and-themonster).